# Distribute events on multiple dates

Tags: javascript, c, react-native, matrix

Hello I have a calendar view(3 day view) and I have to display multiple day events on 3 days view. I am unable to generate the matrix of events

```
3/10/18 | 4/10/18 | 5/10/18
3.......|3........|9.......
........|5........|5.......
7.......|7........|........
```

3...., 5...., 9.... and 7.... are multiple date events that are layered out in a 3 by 3 matrix.

a general event structure is like this

```
{ id: 123, name: "3", startTimestamp: 1538524800 endTimestamp: 1538611200 }
```

I have tried : -

1. Looping over date and for each date find events that are in that date.
2. Finding matrix of each date and events

   But I am unable to align the events in the dates like 3 events is aligned at [0][0] and [0][1] and 5 is aligned at [1][1] and [1][2]

also I am having problem in adding 9 to empty space in [0][2] I am taking index of each column and I am left with 9 at [2][2] the space is empty.

This is my current snippet.

```
let events = [{ id: 3, name: "3", start: 3, end: 4}, { id: 5, name: "5", start: 4, end: 5}, { id: 7, name: "7", start: 3, end: 4}, { id: 9, name: "9", start: 5, end: 9}];

let dates = [3, 4, 5];

function abc1 () {
 let result = [
  [
   undefined, undefined, undefined
  ], [
   undefined, undefined, undefined
  ], [
   undefined, undefined, undefined
  ]
 ];
 for (let i=0; i<dates.length; i++) {
  let date = dates[i];
  let index = 0;
  for (let j=0; j<events.length; j++) {
   let event = events[j];
   if (event.start<= date && date <= event.end) {
    result[index][i] = event.id;
    index ++;
   }
  }
 }
 console.log("Result ", result);
};

Result  [[3, 3, 5], [7, 5, 9], [undefined, 7, undefined]]
```

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: Expected output is : [[3, 3, 9], [undefined, 5, 5], [7, 7, undefined]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct EventsModel {
    var id:Int
    var name: String
    var start:Int
    var end:Int
}
let events = [EventsModel(id: 3, name: "3", start: 3, end: 4), EventsModel(id: 5, name: "5", start: 4, end: 5 ), EventsModel(id: 7, name: "7", start: 3, end: 4), EventsModel(id: 9, name: "9", start: 5, end: 9)]

var dates:[Int] = [3, 4, 5]
var finaloutput:[[String]] = []
dates = dates.sorted()
for event in events {
    var outEventArr:[String] = []
    for date in dates {
        if date >= event.start && date <= event.end {
            outEventArr.append(event.name)
        } else {
            outEventArr.append("undefined")
        }
    }
    finaloutput.append(outEventArr)
}
print(finaloutput)
```

**OUTPUT:-** [["3", "3", "undefined"], ["undefined", "5", "5"], ["7", "7", "undefined"], ["undefined", "undefined", "9"]]

PS:- Pardon me for writing code in swift.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with 3 - Dimensional Array ?

Comment: I have days on x axis and events on y axis. I don't require 3 dimension matrix. Please help with two dimensional matrix.

Comment: And on z-axis you can add events.. Its easy to handle... If you want difficult method, then reply back.

Comment: Events is on y axis (not on z axis). Please check any solution for 2d matrix.